# Performance of local pointer/reference for convenience

Tags: c++

Is there any performance downside when using one of the following methods of accessing an array element?

```
int someRandomArrayWithLongName[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

// case (1): access with alias reference
int &elem = someRandomArrayWithLongName[1];
while (!exit)
{
   ++elem;
}

// case (2): pointer access
int *elem = &someRandomArrayWithLongName[1];
while (!exit)
{
   ++(*elem);
}

// default case (3): conventional element access
while (!exit)
{
   ++someRandomArrayWithLongName[1];
}
```

In particular, will the compiler recognize the aliasing and do its magic to prevent unnecessary memory allocations (case 1 and 2)? Or is it better to just use case 3?

**EDIT**: I used http://gcc.godbolt.org/ as suggested in the comments. Turns out the three cases produce the exact same assembly code ([source](http://goo.gl/wdrSDg)):

```
test1():
    movzbl  exit(%rip), %eax
    testb   %al, %al
    jne .L1
    movl    someRandomArrayWithLongName+4(%rip), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
.L3:
    movzbl  exit(%rip), %edx
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    addl    $1, %eax
    testb   %dl, %dl
    je  .L3
    movl    %ecx, someRandomArrayWithLongName+4(%rip)
.L1:
    rep ret
test2():
    movzbl  exit(%rip), %eax
    testb   %al, %al
    jne .L8
    movl    someRandomArrayWithLongName+4(%rip), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
.L10:
    movzbl  exit(%rip), %edx
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    addl    $1, %eax
    testb   %dl, %dl
    je  .L10
    movl    %ecx, someRandomArrayWithLongName+4(%rip)
.L8:
    rep ret
test3():
    movzbl  exit(%rip), %eax
    testb   %al, %al
    jne .L14
    movl    someRandomArrayWithLongName+4(%rip), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
.L16:
    movzbl  exit(%rip), %edx
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    addl    $1, %eax
    testb   %dl, %dl
    je  .L16
    movl    %ecx, someRandomArrayWithLongName+4(%rip)
.L14:
    rep ret
exit:
    .zero   1
```

Comment: the compiler optimizes your code so judging performance by looking at your source code is futile, instead either produce an assembly listing with a switch on the compiler or time it in your code.

Comment: I would be surprised if the compiler did *not* emit identical asm for all three of those. The only way to know for sure is to take firm grasp of `-S` and run with it.

Comment: There are tools like http://gcc.godbolt.org/ that allows you to easily examine the assembly code generated by a variety of compilers. Use them.

Comment: @T.C. I didn't know about that splendid site! Saves me work.

Comment: gcc.godbolt.org is my new favorite site...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "unnecessary memory allocations" you're worried about only involves a tiny bit of stack space in the worst case, and takes literally no extra time, so it's nothing to worry about.

That said, any modern compiler worth its salt will most likely generate identical code for all three in optimised builds.
In practice, use the one you find most readable (and least error-prone) and rewrite if it turns out to be too slow.

For improved performance you should strive to avoid accessing memory by keeping modifications as local as possible so they can be performed in registers, like this:

```
int increment = 0;
while (!exit)
{
   ++increment;
}
someRandomArrayWithLongName[1] += increment;
```

Comment: +1 for improved code; even if I think compiler's optimization also do that.

Comment: Shouldn't you strive to hit the cache, or avoid *missing* it? ;-)

Comment: @PeterSchneider I meant "hit" as in "access". Bad word choice.

Comment: Well, it's established terminology (cache hit: good; cache miss: bad). "Accessing" is not *that* established any more imo. I guess an "access" could also be a miss, but certainly a hit (meaning the value is in the cache which is desired) would perfectly well qualify as "access". Perhaps you mean "avoid accessing the second level cache and stay in the (little, on-dye) CPU cache"? But that's also a cache (which you really want to access and hit).

Answer (score 1):

In general the third option will perform about as well as your compiler can make array access perform, while the performance of the first two options depends on the compiler's ability to trace the origin of the pointer back to the array.

In particular, a lot of optimizations might be suppressed when writes to arbitrary pointers occurs, as in (1) and (2) - since the compiler has a hard time guaranteeing that various objects in the loop don't [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29). Since the access in (3) is directly to an array of integers, more aggressive optimizations can often be applied (especially enregistration of loop variables).

In the trivial example you gave, aliasing won't be a problem, since the loop does nothing but repeatedly access the same element. I assume your question is more general however - that you are interested in the performance of the approaches in more interesting loops that may very well contain operations where aliasing issues can arise.

Determining whether aliasing or any other (de)optimization has actually occurred is relatively difficult simply by staring at the source code. For example modern compilers might handle all the situations above equivalently, when elem is declared in the same function, but not if elem is passed in from the outside (since compilers have more limited ability to optimize across function calls).

So while there is nothing wrong with understanding the theory, the best approach is to test if it really matters. Time the various approaches *in the actual way they are used in real code*, and if you are up for it, take a peek at the disassembly.

Comment: Hmmm... I like the aliasing concern but I'm not sure the situation improves by writing to the array directly: If there are other pointers around which potentially alias the array the direct access will also have to be less optimized (e.g. needs an extra load from memory).

Comment: The array helps mostly because the compiler has an easier time proving that aliasing is impossible in many cases - e.g., because it can see that the array is stack allocated and doesn't escape, or it can see that the array doesn't alias certain values. If it can't do that, it would have to fall back on type-based "can't alias" rules - which are quite powerful but not universally used since they cause bugs in code which wasn't written with them in mind (in particular, gcc is aggressive about this - but users often have to turn the option off).